Chaining sibling directory imports in Python 3.8+
In my Python project, I am having trouble with sibling directory imports. My file structure is as follows:
main_dir/
        __init__.py
        subdir1/
                __init__.py
                module1.py
                module2.py
        subdir2/
                __init__.py
                module3.py
        setup.py

Importantly, module1.py imports all the functions from module2.py, so in module1.py I have the following import:
from module2 import *

There are functions in module1.py that call functions from module2.py within them.
Running module1.py obviously works fine. The issue is that I need module3.py to import the functions from module1.py. To be very clear, in module3.py, I need to run a function from module1.py that calls a function from module2.py within it.
In other parts of my project, I have been struggling with importing sibling directories. A fix I found that has worked for Python 3.8.0-3.12.2 is to use a setup.py file and, in files that require a sibling import, use
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from sibling_dir.module import needed_fun

This has been working, unlike any other solution I have tried such as
from ..sibling_dir.module import *
or from .. import siblingdir.module.
The setup.py file is as follows:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name = 'example_name', version = '1.0', packages = find_packages())

(this of course requires the external setuptools package to be installed)
However, back to the main problem. I need module3.py to import functions from module1.py. In module3.py, I have tried the usual setup. Since module1.py imports functions from module2.py, I also import module2.py's functions:
In module3.py
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from subdir1.module2 import *
from subdir1.module1 import *

I have also tried
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
import subdir1.module2
from subdir1.module1 import *

When I try to run module3.py, I get "No module named 'module2'". This error occurs on the line from subdir1.module1 import *. I am wondering if there is some secret combination of imports to solve this problem, or a different approach entirely. This structure is important to my project, as organization will be very important as it gets larger. Furthermore, relative paths of some kind are essential, I cannot use absolute paths. One final thing that may matter is that none of the __init__.py's have anything in them, they are there primarily for setuptools to see those directories as packages (I think). I should also clarify that everything I try I have tried after running a fresh pip install . in the main_dir directory to utilize setuptools.py.

See this post

Does this answer your question? Relative imports for the billionth time

As long as the sibling folders are in a shared package, such as main_dir, you can import directly from there.
from main_dir.subdir1.module1 import *


Unfortunately, the same issue persists in that I get the error "No module named 'main_dir'" on the suggested import line.

Try adding main_dir's parent directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. Then solution from this answer should work.

Thank you! While sys.path.append('..') added subdir2's parent to the PYTHONPATH variable (main_dir), using sys.path.append('../..') correctly added main_dir's parent to the PYTHONPATH. I also had to do this double-parent append in module1.py, but it worked in the end.

Nice, glad you figured it out! I strongly recommend you to change every import you have to follow the pattern from main_dir.subdirX.moduleY import.... Then, you will only have to add parent of main_dir to your PYTHONPATH and you are all set :)

After more testing, it seems that this solution of adding the universally shared directory's parent (main_dir's in this case) to PYTHONPATH only works if the CWD is set to the script's directory. It seems like this extends beyond just navigating to the directory of the script, like subdir2 in the question's example. I had to actually add "cwd": "${fileDirname}", to VSCode's launch.json configuration file.
